# What code is put on the Event Loop - the Future body or the call to execute upon its completion (then)?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have a few basic questions about Dart `Futures` that I can't seem to get an answer to myself. Considering the following code:

```dart
Future(
  () => print('from Future') // 1
).then(
  (_) => print('after Future') // 2
);
```

1. What is put on the Event Loop, code block 1 or 2?
2. If 1 is put on the Event Loop, is 2 executed immediately after it, synchronously, or is it put on the Event Loop as well, for later execution?
3. If 2 is executed immediately, would it ever make sense for 2 to be:

```dart
Future.delayed(someDuration, () => print('after Future'));
```

What would the use case be? Like to split a longer 'task' so that other code is run in between? Is it something that is actually done in practice, like in Flutter, to prevent 'jank'?

**Edit**: I found a very insightful article: https://webdev-angular3-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/articles/performance/event-loop#how-to-schedule-a-task, which kind of answers pretty much every single question I asked here.

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor you are calling is `Future()` which are documented as:

> Creates a future containing the result of calling `computation` asynchronously with Timer.run.
>
> If the result of executing `computation` throws, the returned future is completed with the error.
>
> If the returned value is itself a Future, completion of the created future will wait until the returned future completes, and will then complete with the same result.
>
> If a non-future value is returned, the returned future is completed with that value.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Future/Future.html

Where `Timer.run` is documented as:

> Runs the given `callback` asynchronously as soon as possible.
>
> This function is equivalent to `new Timer(Duration.zero, callback)`.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Timer/run.html

So, since we are creating a timer which are already completed, it will immediately be put on the event loop.

So with this knowledge we can answer your questions:

#### What is put on the Event Loop, code block 1 or 2?

Block 1 is put on the event loop. Since block 2 is dependent on the result from block 1, it will not be put on any queue. Instead, block 2 will be notified when block 1 has returned its result.

#### If 1 is put on the Event Loop, is 2 executed immediately after it, synchronously, or is it put on the Event Loop as well, for later execution?

As far as I understand the documentation, block 2 will be executed immediately synchronously as part of the block 1 is completed (unless the future as has already been completed which then will trigger a microtask):

> Register callbacks to be called when this future completes.
>
> When this future completes with a value, the onValue callback will be called with that value. If this future is already completed, the callback will not be called immediately, but will be scheduled in a later microtask.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Future/then.html

#### If 2 is executed immediately, would it ever make sense for 2 to be:

The specific example does not make much sense. But yes, you can use the `Future.delayed` if you want to schedule smaller tasks on the event loop. It should be noted that Dart are single threaded so you cannot schedule tasks to be running in another thread by using `Future.delayed`.

But in the context of Flutter, you properly want to have multiple smaller tasks so the UI can be drawn between each task. But if you are going to make some heavy calculations, you should properly use an `Isolate` to run these in another thread.

Comment: Could you also write 'when' block 1 is put on the Event Queue? Is it when the timer fires? I.e. the Timer firing actually puts the block on the Event Queue?
I mean, when a Timer is fired (as soon as possible or with a delay, doesn't matter), does it actually only put the code to execute on the Event Queue? If this is the case, that would actually explain a lot.

Comment: I am no expert in the inner logic of how the Dart VM are handling timers. You can read the source yourself here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1564d596bb68216d4f0b2cad338a7a62b036f346/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/timer_impl.dart

Comment: About "when" something happens in the specific makes little sense since Dart are still only running in a single thread. Also, when we are talking about event queue it is a little abstract since there are multiple queues inside the Dart VM. E.g. the queue of timers which are going to be triggered sometime in the future but not right now. This timers will prevent the Dart VM from turning off so the Dart VM do have some understanding of what Timers there has been defined.

Comment: What I mean is: with Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), callback) there is a difference whether the callback is put on the queue immediately (which kind of makes no sense), or after 1 second. And since, as per your answer, Futures works with Timers internally, without knowing what and when Timers do, there is no way to really correctly answer my questions.

Comment: Since you are creating a timer which cannot be triggered immediately, it will be put into a queue inside the `_TimerHeap` class to be scheduled later when the times come. There are some logic inside the `_Timer` class which are being use to tell the outside Dart VM how long it should wait before it tries to contact the timer logic again (like the `_scheduleWakeup` method). When the Dart VM contacts the timer class, it will get a list of timers which should be triggered and will then call each callback method assigned to each of the timers.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot from the link to timer source you provided. It also looks like timers are run in a separate isolate, which indirectly clears up a doubt I had.